# T?, nullable type parameter in C# 9

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-9.0

[This program](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLTIPaIMYVQcwgDsIFYMFkAfAAQCYBGAWAChWAVAfgAIwAedgD4AFF24wAlKwDe3Od1bzx3ALzcicADaaA3NwD0+7qQQVF8mgHZuAEwhgoWmKM4SdrAL6tWASzDD/BgAGCW4fZHUtTVDDYwRTBHM5GgYATmEAIg1tDLdWIA===) has two errors:

```
using System;

T? f<T>(T? t)
{    
    t = null; //  Error CS0403  Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type
    return default(T?);
}

if(f(10) is null) // Error  CS0037  Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type    
    Console.WriteLine("null");
```

`T?` has to be a nullable type. But it seems `T?` is the same as `T` in the above program.

Is `?` ignored in `T?`?

---

**Edit**: [Both errors disappear](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLTIPaIMYVQcwgDsIFYMFkAfAAQCYBGAWAChWAVAfgAIwAedgD4AFF24wAlN24B3ABakI3dtxDdkMBHGwxWAb2nTWh8dwC83InAA21gNzcA9I+6kEFY4ZoB2bgBMIMCgbGFFOCTtWAF9WVgBLMGF+OKIYEQYABik45EsbaylnVwR3BE9pGgYATmEAIitbWojWIA===) with a `struct` constraint:

```
using System;

T? f<T>(T? t)  where T : struct
{    
    t = null; // error
    return default(T?);
}

if(f<int>(10) is null) // error
    Console.WriteLine("null");
```

I don't understand why the constraint changes the results.

Comment: The C# language development team decided that it's a good idea for T? to just mean "defaultable" in the unconstrained case, not "nullable". I think that was a really stupid move as it leads to exactly the confusion you're in right now. But yeah: in C#, T? doesn't always mean nullable.

Comment: Subscribing to @stefan 's comment that this is a very counterintuitive aspect of the language.

Comment: @stefan You say `T?` means just "defaultable". But then, `int` (which is defaultable, `default(int)=0`) would be `int?`, which is obviously not true. Can you be more specific regarding "in C#, `T?` doesn't always mean nullable"? Do you have an example for `T` where `T?` can NOT be null?

Comment: That is precisely the point of my dislike of what the C# language team decided there, @Kjara.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `T?` in `T?` and in `(T? t)`, they both refer to nullable reference types, *not* to the special `Nullable<T>` struct. There's no way that you can specify a generic parameter such that you can treat it as a class and a nullable value type.

The second error is just because `f(10)` (so `f<int>(10)`) is implicitly taken as an `int` (as there's no such thing as a nullable reference int value), so `null` isn't valid, just as if you did `if (10 is null)`.

---

If `T` stops being open and instead you add a constraint such as `where T : struct`, `T?` becomes `System.Nullable<T>` rather than a nullable reference parameter, and so the code becomes the exact same as before nullable reference types were introduced.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus That happens because now `T?` is a `Nullable<T> where T: struct`, but you can no longer pass reference types to the method

Comment: So it seems`T?` is regarded as `T` when `T` is a value type and as `T?` when `T` is a reference type. Am I correct?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Yes, that's correct, if you're referring to the original code and not the update

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is this an inherent restriction that cannot be worked with or a design choice? Let's say I have a generic entity, where the generic type denotes a foreign key type. Currently, I either have to lock down the type to value/reference types or get an odd behavior (string?, but long, etc). Before C# 9 we couldn't even use T? without constraints, which felt better, since the current behavior seems very unintuitive, to me, at least.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an idea for the first error, but the second.

`f(10) is null` is inferred as `int` in lieu of `int?` since `10` is of `int` type.
Either `f((int?)10) is null`, or `f<int?>(10) is null` should be used.